# Get seperate information about each JSON element

Tags: php, json

I've JSON as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "..",
    "size": "..",
    "task": ".."
  },
  {
    "id": "..",
    "size": "..",
    "task": "..",
  },
  ...
]
```

My task is to get **plain** JSON code for each element (array). So, for every id (seperate element) I would get it's json information (size, task ect...). How can this be done?

Update: Is there any better way than following?

- json_decode and then loop over each array (because this would give me decoded version, which I don't want right now, so after this procedure, I'd have to encode result again).

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? It's pretty trivial to decode and loop over.

Comment: @Andrew Updated.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$json = array(array('fname'=> "aman", 'lname' => 'kumar', 'email'=> 'developer.amankr@gmail.com'));
$data = json_encode($json);   //[{"fname":"aman","lname":"kumar","email":"developer.amankr@gmail.com"}]
$parse = json_decode($data);
echo $fname = $parse[0]->fname;
echo $lname = $parse[0]->lname;
echo "<br>";
echo $email = $parse[0]->email;
?>
```